# How to parse JSON for highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have this JSON:

```
var z =   [{
        "signed_up": "2015-08-24T10:31:48.294Z",
        "sessions": 10,
        "browser_family": "Chrome",
        "browser_version": "44.0.2403",
        "timestamp": "2015-08-26T08:36:43.973725Z",
        "useremail": "test@test",
    },
    {
        "signed_up": "2015-08-24T10:31:48.294Z",
        "sessions": 10,
        "browser_family": "Chrome",
        "browser_version": "44.0.2403",
        "timestamp": "2015-08-26T08:36:02.765142Z",
        "useremail": "none",
    },
    {
        "signed_up": "2015-08-25T13:57:00.181Z",
        "sessions": 1,
        "browser_family": "Opera",
        "browser_version": "31.0.1889",
        "timestamp": "2015-08-25T13:57:00.181781Z",
        "useremail": "test1@test",
    },
    {
        "signed_up": "2015-08-24T10:31:48.294Z",
        "sessions": 10,
        "browser_family": "Chrome",
        "browser_version": "44.0.2403",
        "timestamp": "2015-08-25T13:53:43.198419Z",
        "useremail": "none",
    },
    {
        "signed_up": "2015-08-24T10:31:48.294Z",
        "sessions": 10,
        "browser_family": "Chrome",
        "browser_version": "44.0.2403",
        "timestamp": "2015-08-25T07:36:39.891389Z",
        "useremail": "test2@test",
    },
    {
        "signed_up": "2015-08-24T12:58:24.480Z",
        "sessions": 1,
        "browser_family": "Chrome",
        "browser_version": "44.0.2403",
        "timestamp": "2015-08-24T12:58:24.480428Z",
        "useremail": "none",
    }];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/25xu5xse/3/

How can I display in the line "X" date and "Y" time ?

I don't know how it all works. I try to use `array[]` and push date + time in 2 different arrays.

Best parse for me looks like:

```
[
 ["2015-08-09", "12:33:12"],
]
```

Comment: What's the format that highcharts expects for date and time?

Comment: Dont you want convert to integer format and after include in highcharts?

Comment: how convert? in timestamp like > 1440510823198 ? but how can display in X date and Y time ?

Comment: 1440510823198 I format line new Data().getTime()

Comment: You can use a Date.UTC() to return a data as timestamp.